# R issues with merge/rbind/concatenate two data frames

Tags: r, merge

I am a beginner with R so i apologise in advance if the question was asked elsewhere. Here is my issue:

I have two data frames, df1 and df2, with different number of rows and columns. The two frames have only one variable (column) in common called "customer_no". I want the merged frame to match records based on "customer_no" and by rows in df2 only.Both data.frames have multiple rows for each customer_no.

I tried the following:

```
merged.df <- (df1, df2, by="customer_no",all.y=TRUE)
```

The problem is that this assigns values of df1 to df2 where instead it should be empty. My questions are:

1) How can I tell the command to leave the unmatched columns empty?
2) How can I see from the merged file which row came from which df? I guess if I resolve the above question this should be easy to see by the empty columns.

I am missing something in my command but don't know what. If the question has been answered somewhere else, would you be still kind enough to rephrase it in English here for an R beginner?

Thanks!

Data example:

```
df1:
customer_no  country  year
  10           UK     2001
  10           UK     2002
  10           UK     2003
  20           US     2007
  30           AU     2006


df2:          
customer_no   income
  10            700
  10            800
  10            900 
  30            1000
```

Merged file should look like this:

```
merged.df:
 customer_no   income  country   year
     10                  UK      2001
     10                  UK      2002
     10                  UK      2003
     10         700
     10         800
     10         900
     30                  AU      2006
     30         1000
```

So:
It puts the columns all together, it adds the values of df2 right after the last one of df1 based on same customer_no and matches only customer_no from df2 (merged.df does not have customer_no 20). Also, it leaves empty all the other cells.

In STATA I use append but not sure in R...perhaps join?

THANKS!!

Comment: Added data. Hope it's clear enough...thanks for your help!!

Comment: This looks more like an rbind than a merge/join, is there a reason why the US entry drops out?

Comment: DMT, yes the reason is because it's not in df2. The merged df excludes values that are only in df1 (not in df2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df1$id <- paste(df1$customer_no, 1, sep="_")
df2$id <- paste(df2$customer_no, 2, sep="_")

res <- merge(df1, df2, by=c('id', 'customer_no'),all=TRUE)[,-1]
res1 <- res[res$customer_no %in% df2$customer_no,]
res1
 #  customer_no country year income
 #1          10      UK 2001     NA
 #2          10      UK 2002     NA
 #3          10      UK 2003     NA
 #4          10    <NA>   NA    700
 #5          10    <NA>   NA    800
 #6          10    <NA>   NA    900
 #8          30      AU 2006     NA
 #9          30    <NA>   NA   1000
```

If you want to change `NA` to `''`,

```
 res1[is.na(res1)] <- '' #But, I would leave it as `NA` as there are `numeric` columns.
```

Or, use `rbindlist` from `data.table` (Using the original datasets)

```
 library(data.table)
 indx <- df1$customer_no %in% df2$customer_no
 rbindlist(list(df1[indx,], df2),fill=TRUE)[order(customer_no)]

 #    customer_no country year income
 #1:          10      UK 2001     NA
 #2:          10      UK 2002     NA
 #3:          10      UK 2003     NA
 #4:          10      NA   NA    700
 #5:          10      NA   NA    800
 #6:          10      NA   NA    900
 #7:          30      AU 2006     NA
 #8:          30      NA   NA   1000
```

Comment: Awesome! THANKS!! What a nightmare this has been...such a relief! :)))

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `smartbind` function from the `gtools` package.

```
require(gtools)
res <- smartbind(df1[df1$customer_no %in% df2$customer_no, ], df2)
res[order(res$customer_no), ]
#      customer_no country year income
#  1:1          10      UK 2001     NA
#  1:2          10      UK 2002     NA
#  1:3          10      UK 2003     NA
#  2:1          10    <NA>   NA    700
#  2:2          10    <NA>   NA    800
#  2:3          10    <NA>   NA    900
#  1:4          30      AU 2006     NA
#  2:4          30    <NA>   NA   1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1$income = df2$country = df2$year = NA
rbind(df1, df2)
  customer_no country year income
1          10      UK 2001     NA
2          10      UK 2002     NA
3          10      UK 2003     NA
4          20      US 2007     NA
5          30      AU 2006     NA
6          10    <NA>   NA    700
7          10    <NA>   NA    800
8          10    <NA>   NA    900
9          30    <NA>   NA   1000
```